# GStreamer Win x64 -- is dshowvideosrc missing?

Tags: c++, gstreamer, directshow, gstreamer-1.0

I have GStreamer 1.12.1 Win64 msi installed (full install), but I cannot find `dshowvideosrc` element.

```
C:\lib\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>gst-inspect-1.0.exe dshowvideosrc
No such element or plugin 'dshowvideosrc'
```

I would like to capture video from a DirectShow video device, but I cannot specify the exact device if I use `autovideosrc` (which uses something to connect to DirectShow under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

I think `dshowvideosrc` was never ported to gstreamer-1.0. I think `ksvideosrc` was kind of meant as a replacement for video device access.

Comment: Thanks! Dug a bit into it and it appears that my (virtual) device I want to capture does not support kernel streaming, so it cannot be opened by `ksvideosrc`.

Comment: Now does this mean that there is no way to achieve what I need? I see that FFmpeg has such DirectShow input device which actually works in my setup, but I want to minimise entropy and switch all components (not just that one) to GStreamer. Am I doomed?

Comment: Since you said `autovideosrc` is kind of working it may help to set `GST_DEBUG` to search the output for hints what element is loaded to access the device - maybe there are others that access the hardware?

Comment: Also check `gst-device-monitor-1.0` if your device is listed there by any chance. That should give you a hint how to access the device via elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, "working" referred to the laptop's camera, which supports kernel streaming...  I actually checked the debug log and I see just one device listed there, which is the camera. All the rest DirectShow video devices (like 5 or so) are not listed for no KS support 